# mysql table schema to actual table

Tags: mysql

I'm very new to databases, so apologies if this is an incredibly stupid quesiton. I was sent the schema of a mysql table in the body of an email. It looks like this, except it has many more rows:

```
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| _id                     | varchar(40)   | NO   | FOO | NULL    |       |
| foo                     | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bar                     | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| baz                     | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qux                     | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I need to create the table locally before reading in the actual data, which is in an accompanying tsv file. I'd rather not create the table schema manually, as it is a lot of columns. Is there a way to do this automatically using the schema that I was sent?

Comment: can't you ask whoever sent you that (what looks like a mysql desc on a table) to jump back on the database and do a "show create tablename"

Comment: I also recommend seeing if the sender has an actual schema dump. It's not very useful to send somebody information about a schema in this form if the intent is for them to recreate what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to automatically convert an ASCII-art table of that form to an SQL CREATE statement.

If you are bored and inclined to do so, I suppose you could write a utility to parse that input and generate an output.

You will either have to create the table with a query (see [`CREATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)), or use an administrative front-end such as *phpMyAdmin* to enter the information in a more human-friendly manner (I believe *phpMyAdmin* also now has a graphical designer feature).

Some other DBMS's have table generation tools built in to their front-ends too, e.g. MS SQL Server Management Studio has a nice graphical table builder.

By the way, to pick nits, you mean to say it is a lot of *columns*, not rows.

---

Edit: Just for fun, here is a quick Linux shell script that converts most of the informational portion of your table to an SQL statement (command line parameter is input file name):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "CREATE TABLE myTable ("
cat "$1" | awk '{ split($0,a,"|"); print a[2] a[3] (match(a[4],"NO")?"NOT NULL":"") " DEFAULT" a[6] ","; }' | tr -s " "
echo ");"
```

The following input file:

```
| _id                     | varchar(40)   | NO   | FOO | NULL    |       |
| foo                     | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bar                     | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| baz                     | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qux                     | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

Generates the following output:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
 _id varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
 foo text DEFAULT NULL ,
 bar text DEFAULT NULL ,
 baz text DEFAULT NULL ,
 qux datetime DEFAULT NULL ,
);
```

But you still have to remove the `foo` line manually and replace `_id` with `foo` (and the `NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL` is odd, I don't actually know of MySQL will accept a null default on a not null column). It doesn't care about your KEY column. You also have to manually delete that last comma. It does do most of the work, though.

Comment: thanks, both for the answer and terminology correction. edited my question to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a start with a good text editor by running through your schema with intelligent replace operations. But in the end it will remain a mainly manual process.

Comment: If you have emacs available (or others with this functionality) you can do rectangle cut (C-x r k) and rectangle type (C-x r t) to change the |'s to whatever.